# Can I make a transition go through a keyframe?

Tags: css

I have a css 'level up' bar defined like so:

```
.levelup-bar {
    background: //;
    color: //;
    -webkit-transition:width .6s ease;
    transition:width .6s ease;
}
```

And it works out quite beautifully indeed, my bar automatically animates when I change the width!

What I am doing is calculating the current rate against a max. Of course, once you reach the max, you level up and it goes back to zero. So once it is 100/100, I'm conditionally making it 0/100 to simulate a level up.

And that is the problem, my bar never reaches 100/100 and it is never truly full.

There is a million and one way to solve this in javascript, but I want to solve it using css3. Is there a way to keyframe my width so that it always goes one way, and resets only to zero once its maxed out?

Plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/N42aoxfJzpIjhWMofmIP?p=preview

Comment: Change if(cur >= max) to if(cur > max), else you can't go to 100%

Comment: @ôkio That would work, but it should wrap around once it reaches 100%. If I use > it will only wrap around once I reach more than 100 (i.e. the bar stays full, instead of going back to 0 automatically)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there won't any CSS solution for you. CSS animation is not for such a purpose (because the keyframes are fixed), CSS transition can only animate between 2 points of value.

Comment: @KingKing I can actually accept that, because my question is 'Can I' instead of an actual 'how to' :)

Answer (score 0):

On your onclick event on the button you have the following:

```
   cur += 10;
   if(cur>=max)
      cur = 0;
```

If you change the if statement from >= to > the bar will fill up if it reaches 100 exactly:

```
   cur += 10;
   if(cur>max)
      cur = 0;
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the solution you are after.

If it goes over the 100 you could stop it at 100, then set a timer to add the remainder of the score after x ms (but then you are using Javascript again) ?

Comment: Yup, I already addressed this (look at comments). Basically it stays at 100 and not wraps around automatically, and as you've said its solvable by a timeout but I don't want to use js and am curious if this is solvable in css3

Comment: Well, since CSS is meant for styling your page it is not really meant for such functional behaviour. Javascript is perfectly fine for this (in fact you are already using javascript to make this solution work)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :

```
// reset cur when you click and you are already at 100%
if(cur >= max)
    cur = 0;

cur += 10;

if(cur > max)
    cur = 0;
```